# Can I check health of a Cloud Run Services without triggering its cold start?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have a problem where we have a WebSocket connection to a Cloud Run Service that is preceded by a health check to the mentioned service.
The issue we face is that every health check is keeping the Run Service alive or cold starting it. What we want is only connect *if* the service is up and running.

What we need therefore is a check if the Cloud Run Service is up and running **without** waking it up. A request therefore somewhat does not help since it will always wake the service up.

Any ideas how to make this happen? *We can not use the cloud API for this case since we can not have credentials available in the clients.*

Comment: Without credentials, you/code can detect nothing regarding a Cloud Run instance. The only method that I know of to detect a running Cloud Run instance is to parse the Cloud Run logs.

Comment: hm maybe I have to deploy a function that uses a gcloud command to check the state

Comment: Cloud Run does not have an API to check if an instance is warm (running).

Comment: Are you sure I can't list run services and see their status? That's odd

Comment: Do you want to use the Cloud Run scalability (up and down (to 0?))?

Comment: I don't fully understand OP's requirements. But the new health checks might help: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks

Comment: Yes, you can list the Cloud Run services, but that does not indicate if an instance is warm or if a cold start is required. I am not aware of a method to achieve your objective - detect if an instance is running without the side effect of starting an instance. Cloud monitoring does know this information, check those APIs. You would have to implement your own status-keeping system.